# node module installation causing error when mixing

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack

I have a server running on laravel, and I want to add a node module named "nodemailer" into it. But whenever I had `npm run watch` running in the background or `npm run dev` ran, it would show errors if I install "nodemailer".
The errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js'
 @ ./resources/js/index.js 1:0-61 24:4-23 26:13-32 100:4-23 102:13-32 160:4-23 161:13-32 186:4-23 187:13-32 216:4-23 218:13-32 257:4-23 260:13-32 306:4-23 309:13-32 355:4-23 358:13-32 399:4-23 402:13-32 442:4-23 445:13-32 493:4-23 496:13-32 535:4-23 538:13-32 580:4-23 582:13-32 618:4-23 620:13-32 657:4-23 659:13-32
 @ multi ./resources/js/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/process/browser.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/process/browser.js'
 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js 1:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js
 @ ./node_modules/axios/index.js
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js'
 @ ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.dev.js 1:0-44
 @ ./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/runtime/componentNormalizer.js'
 @ ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 7:0-93 8:16-26
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.umd.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.umd.js'
 @ ./resources/js/index.js 7:0-43 700:19-23 705:19-23 705:28-32
 @ multi ./resources/js/index.js

ERROR in (webpack)/buildin/global.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js'
 @ ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-41
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js

ERROR in (webpack)/buildin/module.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/****/projects/githubs/####/node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js'
 @ ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 1:0-41
 @ ./resources/js/bootstrap.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js
```

I've already tried installing using yarn, it said the node engine was expecting an older version but it worked when I opened an empty file just for this module

Comment: Try npm install or downgrading node to that older version and then npm install again.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following steps:

- Stop the watch script, if it is running.
- Run `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` to get rid of any old, maybe broken, dependencies.
- Run `npm install`, to install everything cleanly from scratch.
- Run your code again.

Supposed that all the dependencies you need are registered in the `package.json` file (and your code is correct), things should work now.

Comment: But I'm not sure if all the dependencies are in the package.json file. Are there any ways to list all the modules in package.json file?